# Using native maps in react-native-maps

Tags: google-maps, react-native, mapkit, expo, react-native-maps

I am using Expo framework to develop a cross platform react-native application. I use `<MapView>` component to display a map.

In order to force the applications to use native maps framework (MapKit on iOS and GoogleMaps in Android),

1. Do we have to configure the provider prop as {undefined} or {null}?
2. Does it achieve the same result if we remove the provider prop?
3. Does it randomly select between MapKit and Google Maps when a
   provider prop is not specified and run in iOS?

In other words does both examples below use native maps framework on the specific OS ?

ex 1 -

```
 <MapView
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 65.7843,
      longitude: -42.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0526,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0825,
    }}
  />
```

ex 2 -

```
<MapView
    provider={undefined}
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 65.7843,
      longitude: -42.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0526,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0825,
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

By default MapKit is for iOS and GoogleMaps is for android even when provider prop is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

From [react-native-maps document](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md):

for `provider`,

> Either "google" for GoogleMaps, otherwise null or undefined to use the native map framework (MapKit in iOS and GoogleMaps in android).

So  if you don't set it, it will use **MapKit** on iOS and **Google Maps** on Android.

Answer (score 0):

On android it will work fine without providing `provider` prop, but on IOS, by default it will use the Apple Mapkit, to change it you need to provide `provider` prop and the value = `google`.